# undefined reference to <function name> in the same project file

Tags: c

[image]

I'm using codeblocks IDE and I don't know what is the problem.

I tried making the variables global but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, do not post a picture of code, post the real code here. People should not have to go offsite to see your code, nor can people copy and test your code if you post a pic. I guess you can edit your post, so please do so. To mark a piece of text as code, select the entire code and then press the "{}" icon on the top of the question editor.

Comment: Also, please read how to ask a question. Your question does not contain enough info for most people to be able to answer it.

Comment: Case (upper/lower) is important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the function name. `Calculate_area` has a capital 'C' in its function declaration name, but not in the prototype declaration.

Change your function declaration at line 31 with:

```
unsigned long calculate_area(unsigned long side);
```